# How to cover ember-simple-auth with acceptance tests?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to cover sign in page with acceptance tests. Small example:

```
test('visiting /sign-in', function(assert) {
  visit('/sign-in');

  fillIn('.t_sign-in_email', 'tony.stark@example.com');
  fillIn('.t_sign-in_password', 'secret-password');
  click('.t_sign-in_submit');

  andThen(() => assert.equal(currentURL(), '/'));
});
```

But when it calls click function it immediately throws error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

If I try sign in manually it works perfectly. Please help to find out what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above seems fine. I think your route handler expects a JSON string but receives something else. Are you using mirage?

Comment: You are right. I'm using mirage and for test env it is trying to connect to mirage, where the problem comes from. Sorry for dummy question. Thank you.